# создание приложения yandex

Tags: python, яндекс-диск

как можно решить данную проблему.
хочу использовать библиотеку yadisk, но для неё необходимо создать приложение в яндексе, но при создании нет пунктов работы с яндекс диском (скриншот прикладываю).
можно ли как-то решить данную проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предлагаю, во-первых, закончить процесс создания. Возможно, потом все станет ясно (никогда не пробовал, просто предположение)

Comment: да я пробовал, там после есть кнопка редактирования, но вот никаких доп настроек для работы с диском так и не появилось

Comment: А где вы создаёте приложение? По идее вам сюда: https://oauth.yandex.ru/client/new

Comment: и вот всё что я вижу, добавил новый скриншот

Comment: Поищи там `disk`

Comment: не знаю, но я к сожалению не могу найти ничего подобного(

Comment: Вот https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXGdT.png

Comment: боже мой, спасибо вам, вы мой герой, оказывается в поле можно писать и происходит поиск<3